# I'm getting incorrect results from MathUtil.round(). Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: codenameone

I put this code into my start() method:

```
float dummy = -4.3219876F;
int rounded = MathUtil.round(dummy);
System.out.println("Float  " + dummy + " rounded = " + rounded);
double dummy2 = -4.3219876;
long rounded2 = MathUtil.round(dummy2);
System.out.println("double " + dummy + " rounded = " + rounded2);
```

It's printing this out:

```
Float  -4.3219876 rounded = -3
double -4.3219876 rounded = -3
```

The round method looks like this:

```
public static int round(float a) {
    return (int)(a + 0.5f);
}
```

If the integer truncation were defined the mathematician's way (greatest integer less than or equal to the number) Then the truncation of -3.8 would be -4, and this would work fine. But it's not defined that way. This method should be written something like this:

```
public static int round(float a) {
    if (a < 0) {
        return (int)(a - 0.5f);
    } else {
        return (int)(a + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had previously written a post (now deleted) that this problem had gone away, but I was wrong. (It went away because I had used Math.round() instead of MathUtil.round(). When I use MathUtil.round(), the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have since discovered that if I use java.lang.Math instead of com.codename1.util.MathUtil, it works fine, even after I send it to my Android. I had avoided java.lang.Math because the presence of MathUtil led me to believe that Math was a forbidden class. Should I avoid using the MathUtil class (which doesn't work)?

Comment: Math would be better in this case as the compiler has some special optimizations for it on iOS. I'll fix `MathUtil` to just call `Math`, it's a pretty old class so it's possible it includes leftovers.

Comment: Thank you. I should probably mention that I discovered that Math.atan() didn't build, so I had to use MathUtil.atan(). So MathUtil would be a good way to go.